# Creating colour fonts using Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-recommendation, fonts

I see a few options to convert whatever we throw in as a font glyph for Windows. Is there anything similar we can use for Ubuntu?

[image]

The above image is from [FontSelf Maker](https://creativemarket.com/blog/how-to-create-a-color-font)

I have FontForge, but it has very limited options. Any help will be great. Thanks.

Comment: Colour font is not limited to a particular colour or gradient. Please see :  https://fonts.google.com/knowledge/introducing_type/introducing_color_fonts